# Angular4 ngFor error - Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular

I'm learning Angular 4. I am trying to display the results of a call to my backend API. I'm getting the data fine. I want to display it. Here is the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; 
import { QuizService } from '../services/quiz.service';

@Component({ 
    selector: 'board', 
    templateUrl: './board.component.html', 
    styleUrls: ['./board.component.css']
})

export class Board {
    constructor(private service: QuizService) {}

    quizzes: any[]; 

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.getQuizzes()
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.quizes = res.json(); 
                console.log(this.quizzes)
            }), error => {
                console.error(error)
            }
    }
}
```

Here is where I am attempting to use ngFor:

```
<div className="board"> 
    <div className="board-container">
       <li *ngFor="let quiz of quizzes">
           {{ quiz.title }}
       </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

This raises this error:

"Board.html:3 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

I'm following a tutorial and have done similar things before... can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. The data IS coming through.

Comment: Can you show console.log(this.quizes) because I don't know structure

Comment: What does you quizes array look like?

Comment: The problem was it needed to be: 

this.quizes = res.json().quizes

The call doesn't return the array, it returns an object containing the array. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was it needed to be:

this.quizzes = res.json().quizzes

The call doesn't return the array, it returns an object containing the array. Adding the extra .quizzes gets you inside the array and makes the error go away.